# A stream "cannot resolve method" that exists

Tags: java, java-stream

Why doesn't the problematic line work? The IDE says

> Cannot resolve method 'identify(String[])'"

but it's right. there

```java
public class PersonApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (areValidArgs(args)) {
            Operations.findAppropriateOperation(args).execute();
        }
    }

    public static boolean areValidArgs(String[] args) {
        return args.length > 0;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class Operations {
    private static Operation[] operations; // let Spring inject all beans of type Operation
    
    @Autowired
    public void setOperations(Operation[] operations) {
        Operations.operations = operations;
    } 

    public static Operation findAppropriateOperation(String[] args) {
        Optional<Operation> operationOptional = Arrays.stream(operations)
                .findFirst(op -> op.identify(args)); // this line is problematic
/*
If I change the statement above to

        Optional<Operation> operationOptional = Arrays.stream(operations)
                .filter(op -> op.identify(args))
                .findFirst();

it works, but I can't stop thinking why the initial code didn't
*/
        return operationOptional
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported argument"));
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class Operation {
    protected final PersonService personService;

    public abstract boolean identify(String[] args); // here!
    public abstract void execute();
}
```

```java
// sample operation

@Component
public class CreatePersonTableOperation extends Operation {
    public CreatePersonTableOperation(PersonService personService) {
        super(personService);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean identify(String[] args) {
        return args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("1");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        personService.createPersonTable();
    }
}
```

I thought maybe `Arrays.stream()` returns a stream of `Object`s (for example, `stream.toArray()` returns an array of `Object`s so streams and arrays don't get along very well), but I checked the docs, and it doesn't

> `public static <T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array)`
>
> Returns a sequential Stream with the specified array as its source.
>
> **Type Parameters:**
>
> T - The type of the array elements
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> array - The array, assumed to be unmodified during use
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a Stream for the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `void Operation#identify(String[])` exists, `Optional<T> Stream#findFirst(Predicate<? super T>)` does not.

[`Stream#findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) is parameterless method.

Since there is no parameter, the Java compiler cannot infer the type of the lambda `op` parameter. It can only do that if there is a SAM type available to match against.

If you want to find the first item based on a given predicate, you have to [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) the stream first:

```
Optional<Operation> operationOptional = Arrays.stream(operations)
        .filter(op -> op.identify(args))
        .findFirst();
```